# C++ set font color to black

Tags: winapi, windows-console

PS: I am using Code::blocks
no conio2.h available

I want to set the font color to black by windows API

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), XXXXXX);
```

What should I fill in XXXXXX?

Comment: Have you read [the example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974.aspx) ?

Comment: It don't answer my question, i need to enter no rgb to make it black, then the compiler tell me i must fill something in XXXXXX

Comment: I gave you a link to an example using `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.

Comment: Is this windows?  If so please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088.aspx#_win32_character_attributes):

> The foreground attributes specify the text color. The background attributes specify the color used to fill the cell's background. The other attributes are used with DBCS.
>
> An application can combine the foreground and background constants to achieve different colors. For example, the following combination results in bright cyan text on a blue background.
>
> ```
> FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_BLUE\
> ```
>
> If no background constant is specified, the background is black, and **if no foreground constant is specified, the text is black. For example, the following combination produces black text on a white background.**
>
> ```
> BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED
> ```

Comment: @Echo: If you want to leave the background alone, you'll need to first read the current attributes.

Comment: OK, can you answer me what does | operator does here first?

Comment: @Echo: It is the bitwise-OR operator.  It produces a result that has a bitflag set if it was set in any of the input operands.

Answer (score 1):

The font color is represented by the combination of several possible attributes:

```
FOREGROUND_BLUE       Text color contains blue.  
FOREGROUND_GREEN      Text color contains green.  
FOREGROUND_RED        Text color contains red.  
FOREGROUND_INTENSITY  Text color is intensified.
```

In your case, since you want the foreground color to be black, you have to pass *no attributes at all*:

```c++
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0);
```

As Ben Voigt points out in the comments below, this will result in black text on a black background. You might want to specify a combination of background attributes in order for the text to readable. For instance (black on white):

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
    BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
```

Comment: That will make both foreground and background black... probably not very useful.

Comment: @Ben, I thought that was the effect the questioner was looking for (masked text). You have a point, though.